# Do I need to repeat a verb in a second clause?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-patterns, omissibility

> - He **will not only** pass the exam **but will also** excel in sports.
> - He **will not only** pass the exam **but also** excel in sports.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

They are both grammatical. Which to use is a matter of style.

When you use [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), the thing that comes before *both* parts does not need to be included in either part.

However, what should come *before* is also up to interpretation—as is if it should be fully or partially used:

- He will <sup>not only pass the exam</sup> but <sup>[also] excel in sports.</sup>
- He not only will <sup>pass the exam</sup> but <sup>[also] excel in sport.</sup>
- He not only <sup>will pass the exam</sup> but <sup>will [also] excel in sports.</sup>

Note that I have put *also* in brackets because it could be considered redundant. That's not necessarily bad, but it, too, is an optional part of the sentence.

---

However, ellipsis does not *need* to be used in any way at all.

In fact a version of the sentence that uses no ellipsis ***at all*** would not drop the repetition of the pronoun either:

- He will not only pass the exam, but he will also excel in sports.

---

All of those versions are possible.

So, no, you don't need to repeat the verb (or the pronoun). It's a matter of personal choice, and whatever style guide that might be followed, if you do or not.

Answer (score -3):

Either sentence seems to convey the meaning in a doubtful way and for that reason I'd use the following construction.

- Not only will he pass the exam but he will also excel in sports.